# jakarta.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL not converting empty strings to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-tomee

The Empty String Madness continues. My form values that are strings are being injected in the backing bean as empty strings, not null as expected.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.0</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0-RC2</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The context parameter in web.xml is supposed to enable interpreting submitted string values as null. (I won't get into the whole making null string values empty strings in the first place thing)

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>jakarta.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Server is Tomcat v10.0.27 within TomEE Plus 9.1.0.

It looks like TomEE is automatically supplying org.apache.myfaces for the JSF implementation:

```
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/10.0.27 (9.1.0)    
INFO: Registering OpenAPI servlet on /openapi for application 
Jul 20, 2023 3:41:47 PM org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer onStartup
INFO: Using OmniFaces version 4.2
INFO: MyFaces Core Servlet 4.0 support enabled
```

I've found that following https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html helpful over the years. I've tried Dynamic Web Module 5.0 & 4.0. There may be something that I am missing in configuring JSF?
[image: Screenshot of Eclipse IDE Project Facets Settings Page]
[image: Another Screenshot of Eclipse IDE Project Facets Settings Page]
Thank you,

Edit: FYI - BalusC EmptyToNullStringELResolver at the link above still manipulates submitted empty strings for JSF 4.0. Change the javax.* imports to

```
import jakarta.el.ELContext;
import jakarta.el.ELResolver;
```

Comment: Yep there is going to be lots of pain like this moving from javax to jakarta.

Comment: We are migrating to the same tech-stack (jakartaee 9.1 with tomee 9.1) and have had BalusC EmptyToNullStringELResolver in action for our application using javaEE 7 and tomcat 7.1 successfully before. Can confirm it is still needed to get the expected result of null values for input fields.